# Insert and read in a txt file using php

Tags: php

I created a form using html which contains a text box and a password box.

I want when I click on the submit button to save the user and the date he entred to the page in a text file, then in the action page the txt file will be displayed and if there is a carriage return it will do the same in the action page.

this is the code I tried in the action page:

```
<?php

$mdpx = "BTS12";
$loginx = "BTS";

$login = $_POST['nom'];
$mdp = $_POST['psw'];
if(!empty($login) AND !empty($mdp))
{
    if($mdp  == $mdpx AND $login == $loginx)
    {
        $fichier = "monfichier.txt";
        $fp = fopen($fichier, "a+");
        flock($fp,LOCK_EX);
        $text .= 'Nom: '.$login."\r\n".'La date: '.date("d M Y : H i s",strtotime("now"))."\r\n".'****************************'."\r\n";
        fputs($fp, $text);
        flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);

        $fp = fopen($fichier,"r");
        flock($fp,LOCK_SH);
        while(!feof($fp))
        {
            $char = fgetc($fp);
            echo ($char == '\r\n') ? '<br/>' : $char;
        }
        flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else
        print 'Le nom d\'utilisateur ou bien le mot de passe est incorrect <br/> Cliquer <a href="index.php">ici</a> pour revounir a la page d\'acceuil';
}
else
    print 'Veuillez remplir tous les champs <br/> Cliquer <a href="index.php">ici</a> pour revounir a la page d\'acceuil';
?>
```

**but the problem is that the action page doesn't do the carriage return.**

I tried also the method readfile() but it didn't worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output the file in a `<pre>` element:

```
echo '<pre>';
readfile($fichier);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: It worked thanks, but why it giving me this message:
`Notice: Undefined variable: text in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\ex\traitement.php on line 24`

Comment: Because you wrote `$text .= "Nom: ...";`. `.=` means to append to the existing string, but you never initialized it before that. Change it to `$text = "Nom: ...";`.

Comment: Okey thanks, I used another method and it worked too.

`while(!feof($fp))
        {
        $char = fgets($fp);
        echo $char;
 echo '<br/>';
        }`

Comment: Don't call it `$char` if it's actually a whole line, that will confuse readers of your code (like me).

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
$char == '\r\n'
```

it will be work